# What are the P4 commandments?

Tags: perforce

I have heard that Perforce has some Commandments, but I don't know what they are. Is there a way to get the p4 client to show them to me?

I've tried to run `strings` across the binary and search for them, but this command returns no results:

```
strings /usr/local/bin/p4 | grep -i commandments
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not describe a problem.

Comment: Raedwald: I tried very hard to phrase the question as though it was a problem. You might want to update the [easter-eggs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/easter-eggs) tag wiki to describe the sort of question that would be appropriate, or vote to delete that tag if you think there are no useful questions in it at all?

Answer (score 3):

The P4 Commandments are an Easter egg hidden inside the `p4` binary. Run `p4 help commandments` to see them for yourself:

```
P4 Commandments -- Values we work by

* We have high standards.
* We are straightforward.
* We rise to responsibility.
* We like work we can be proud of.
* We like to hear what we've done.
* We value both people skills and job skills.
* We treat each other with dignity and respect.
* We are one team. We are not in competition with each other.
* We talk and listen. We like feedback.
* We appreciate creative and practical solutions. There might be
  a better way.
* We appreciate people for who they are.
* Fun is always an option. It is not mandatory.
* These are the best years of our lives.
```

Comment: What are they trying to say with "* Fun is always an option. It is not mandatory." Sounds like they don't want to have fun if they can avoid it to me.

Comment: *a wild Perforcian appears* We're trying to make it clear that while we like to have fun, people can opt out if they want to. Not everyone likes to party/hangout with their co-workers and we want folks to know that is ok.

Comment: Close :-). The P4 Commandments are actually stored inside the server executable p4d together with all the other help texts.

Comment: Those are indeed the best years of my life so far! ;-)